# What to do after a revert commit on sourcetree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I accidentally pushed some wrong code to `origin/my_branch`. My local was up to the same as the `origin/my_branch`. So after I clicked "revert commit" on the `origin/my_branch`, my local is one commit ahead of `origin/my_branch`. Now I want to "unstage" some changes from `local/my_branch` so I can push the right code to `origin/my_branch`. I don't know how to do this "unstage" in Sourcetree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

Comment: The action you are looking for is `git reset` Search "how to undo changes in git" on google, I suggested one of the questions on SO as a possible solution.

Comment: No it doesn't. Three differences: 1. I've pushed my wrong codes to the origin, and I've reverted the origin to the stage before my wrong commit. 2. Changes are still in my local, which I want to cherrypick to push again. 3. How to do this in sourcetree instead of in git?

Comment: I've done revert (reset). What I'm looking for is how to cherrypick my changes (all staged) from my local (1 commit ahead of the origin coz I've reverted my change in origin) and push them to the origin again.

Comment: you created a new commit locally with revert. No deal: git commit --amend to modify the revert, or git reset. You won't be able to remove the commit from remote without force pushing.